# Chart.js remove zero value sector in pie chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Chart.js
Please help: how remove zero value sector in pie chart.
In data: [12,0,0];
version: 2.9.4
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIfAq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible by using the scriptable option for borderwidth like this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "f", "d"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 0, 0],
      borderWidth: (a, b, c) => (a.dataset.data[a.dataIndex] === 0 ? 0 : 1),
      backgroundColor: ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "white", "black"],
      borderColor: ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink", "purple", "white", "black"]
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

if you change `borderWidth: (a,b,c) => (a.dataset.data[a.dataIndex] === 0 ? 0 : 1),` to `borderWidth: (a,b,c) => (a.dataset.data[a.dataIndex] === 0 ? 10 : 1),` you can see the old behaviour you have now.